# How to create a layout-sw380dp folder in Android Studio step by step

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create a layout folder for a 18:9 screen.
How can I do this in Android Studio?
I am going to

> File -> New -> Android resource directory -> then selecting Layout in resource type.

Then, what should be the next step?
Please give me a step by step how-to.

Comment: just create a simple directory and name it layout-sw380dp

Comment: that is not working

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

To create different layout folders, right click on res folder. Then navigate to **New>Android Resource Directory**. Set **resource type to layout** in the dropdown.

After that in the **Available Qualifiers** list, select **screen width**. When you select screen width, click on **>>** button. Then it will open a text box, type your desired width their without dp

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your current project folder. (For Example:- \YourProject)
2. Now open :- YourProject\app\src\main\res
3. Create Folder which having a name of (layout-sw380dp)
4. Now copy all layout from YourProject\app\src\main\res\layout folder and paste into newly created folder having a name of (layout-sw380dp)
5. Now open YourProject in Android Studio and clean the project

Now, you successfully created 380dp layout for your project. right now only you have to do that set a width and height appropriate for the display and adjust it.

You can also created another 360dp layout or any other layout with same process.